# CSV Output Unreadable

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I'm trying to export the results of this simple script to a .csv file. I get the results but it either returns information about data of the results or a long jumble of data I'm sure how to parse correctly.

```
<# 
Will ping all devices in list and display results as a simple UP or DOWN, color coded Red or Green.
#>


$Names = Get-Content -Path "C:\TestFolder\GetNames.txt"

$Output = @() 

foreach ($name in $names)
{

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            $Result1 += "$name, up" 
            Write-Host "$name, up" -ForegroundColor Green
           
        }

    else
        
        {
          $Result2 += "$name, down" 
          Write-Host "$name, down" -ForegroundColor Red

        }
    }

$Output += $Result1, $Result2
$Output = $Output | Select-Object 

$Output | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\psCSVFiles\mycsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Results of this return:
Length
49768
25081

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In case you're wondering about your CSV output, $Output is an array that contains 2 strings ($Result1 and $Result2).  When exported to CSV, it shows you the  Length of each string contained within $Output.  Not very useful, I agree.  See Mattias's answer below for a more robust CSV output.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to "format" the output strings manually - `Export-Csv` will take care of that part.

What you want to do is create *objects* with properties corresponding to the columns you want in your CSV:

```
$Names = Get-Content -Path "C:\TestFolder\GetNames.txt"

$Output = foreach ($name in $names) {
  # test if computer is reachable/pingable
  $isUp = Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet

  # construct output object with results
  [pscustomobject]@{
    ComputerName = $name
    Status = if($isUp){ 'Up' }else{ 'Down' }
  }
}

# Export to CSV
$Output |Export-Csv -Path 'C:\psCSVFiles\mycsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Alternatively, use `Select-Object` to modify the input strings directly using the pipeline:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\TestFolder\GetNames.txt" |Select @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Status';Expression={if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet){'Up'}else{'Down'}}} |Export-Csv -Path 'C:\psCSVFiles\mycsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```